# JSON object without knowing the KEY names and COLUMN names in order to access the elements

Tags: json, ajax, jpa

I am working on jpa query with specific only 3 columns, but it did not get the column name even I did name the query column,then this is what my Json response look like

```
[["123","name1","age15"],["124","name2","age12"],["125","name3","age14"]]
```

This is what i did

```
<table id="resultTable" border="1"></table>
.
.
success : function(data) {

                    var html = '';
                    var index = [];


                    for (var x in data) {
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += "<td>" +  data[index.push(x)] + "</td>" 
                                +"<td>"+  data[index.push(x)] + "</td>"
                                +"<td>"+  data[index.push(x)] + "</td>"
                        html += "</tr>";
                    }

                    $('#resultTable').html(html);
```

[And this is the result which i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwG8n.jpg)

[However, This is what i expect for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx5Ux.jpg)

Again , the reason that I query for only 3 column is that i keep facing the

> JsonMappingException:failed to lazily initialize a collectin of role:

,but what i am really want is only 3 columns, not the whole of the entity' column. Well my jpql query look like this

```
("SELECT s.Id,s.name,s.age FROM Student s").getResultList();
```

Comment: you have some JPA entity, but it is not posted. You go on about JSON, but why not focus your question on getting data back from JPA then you identify where the "problem" is.

Comment: well, i did but this is the only one that i got the list of data. I did put '@JsonIgnore' on the relationship '@ManytoOne' however it did not seem to  be worked. So, i make this  question out.

Comment: so you haven't bothered debugging whether the query returns correct info then? Look JPA query is one process, conversion to JSON is another. Which works? Putting some annotation on a class when you are returning an Object[] from a query is kinda pointless ... assuming the query output is what is converted into JSON. But then who knows since it is undefined